# Facebook app is showing disabled in the FB dev console

Tags: facebook-graph-api, magento2, facebook-login

I have followed all the steps for app verification and also done the business verification still the app shows disabled and there is no option to enable it.

Also, when I click on read more and appeal it shows "You don't have any required action items to display. If any of your apps need immediate attention in the future, an item will show here."

What can I do to make the app live?

And also in the facebook login is shows an error ""Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

I have added domain and everything properly.

Try requesting access but nothing changed.